# How do I create a dynamic SQL string using Parameters?

Tags: php, sql

I'm stuck with this portion where I know there is definitely a way to do this dynamically, but I just don't know how.

How do I, upon receiving a search query, and knowing how many arrays are in the search query, dynamically creates a SQL string?

Below are parts of the code shown. Any help is appreciated, thanks! =)

```
if ($arraycount ==2){
    $searchSQL = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IN (SELECT field2 FROM $table WHERE field3 IN ('$array[0]','$array[1]'));");
}
else if ($arraycount ==3){
    $searchSQL = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IN (SELECT field2 FROM $table WHERE field3 IN ('$array[0]','$array[1]','$array[2]'));");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to concatenate values of an array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 
        (SELECT field2 FROM $table 
          WHERE field3 IN ('".implode("','", $array)."')";
$searchSQL = $db->query($sql);
```

Here is **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HTeKas)** demo.

Comment: this is vulnerable with sql injection.

Comment: @LeeLoo意 Yes, it might be. But we don't know for sure where $array comes from based on OP's question, do we?

Comment: OMG saved my day! I've been thinking it for the whole morning. I'm not worried about sql injection as this site is just for self use, furthermore I am only granted the "read only" permission. Appreciated and thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @peterm, but with extra security measure (if you use MySQL)

```
... implode("','", array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $array))
```